# GTM + GA4: Track views on the multi-step form without URL page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have a following issue I cannot find a solution for.
I have a form on my site containing of X step form. Proceeding from one step to another is realized without any page reload or even without url change (no parameter is added to the url). The only way to differientiate each of the steps is the fact that the step heading is a span with ID=step_1 (and so on with following steps).

What I'm trying to do is to trigger an event on the view of each step of the form.

Initially I was thinking about triggering an event once user clicks on 'Save' button which allows user to go to the next step. However - as 'Save' step might return validation error, it will not work.
What also makes it more difficult is the fact that once user leaves the form unfinished, on the next visit step he left the form is displayed (so actually he might restart on for example Step 3).

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use the element visibility trigger and fire on the different steps available based on the element id.

More info about this here:
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679410?hl=en

An even more robust way is by modifying your website code and doing a dataLayer.push when each step triggers. That way you can use an event trigger which simplifies everything a lot.